# Stored procedure call from Enitiy Framwork 5 to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to make a stored procedure call from Entity fromawork 5.0 to MySQL. I am able to connect to MySQL but when I am making call to stored procedure,I am getting empty entites(no data). How could I resolve this issue -

Below code I am using to make call to stored procedure -

```
public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetFileType_Result> usp_GetFileType()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GetFileType_Result>("usp_GetFileType");
        }
```

I observe on more thing is that whenever I am updating .edmx file from stored porcedure I am getting empty model like this -

```
namespace MySQLwithEntity
    {
        using System;

        public partial class usp_GetFileType_Result
        {

        }
    }
```

So I filled it manually like below -

```
namespace MySQLwithEntity
    {
        using System;

        public partial class usp_GetFileType_Result
        {
          public int FileTypeId { get; set; }
          public string FileTypeName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

But still I am getting empty values -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours I found solution of this.It might helpful for someone -

Reason of above way of calling SP from MySQL was not working was autogenerated entity model was blank, .edmx file was NOT generating mapping for the columns those were returning from MySQL SP.

```
namespace MySQLwithEntity
    {
        using System;

        public partial class usp_GetFileType_Result
        {

        }
    }
```

Put entititis manually -

```
namespace MySQLwithEntity
    {
        using System;

        public partial class usp_GetFileType_Result
        {
          public int FileTypeId { get; set; }
          public string FileTypeName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Created mappinng manually in .edmx file like below, although it is not recommended, but I had no choice. .edmx file will have to edit for "CSDL content" section and "C-S mapping content" section when you open it as xml file -

```
 <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="usp_GetFileType" FunctionName="Model1.Store.usp_GetFileType">
              <ResultMapping>
              <ComplexTypeMapping TypeName="Model1.usp_GetFileType_Result">
                <ScalarProperty Name="FileTypeId" ColumnName="FileTypeId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FileTypeName" ColumnName="FileTypeName" />
              </ComplexTypeMapping>
            </ResultMapping>
          </FunctionImportMapping>
```

Second is, the code to call to SP. I changed code to call SP like below -

```
public virtual IList<usp_GetFileType_Result> GetCustOrderHist()
        {
            IList<usp_GetFileType_Result> data = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<usp_GetFileType_Result>("CALL usp_GetFileType();").ToList();

            return data;
        }
```

`Call` in MySQL is equivelent of `EXEC` of MS SQL.